# Access violation using flann matcher

Tags: c++, opencv, access-violation, flann

I'm facing a very annoying problem when I create an object of FalnnBaseMatcher.

The code is the following and it worked fine on ubuntu under eclipse.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "C:\openCv\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "C:\openCv\opencv\build\include\opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "C:\openCv\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "C:\openCv\opencv\build\include\opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"
#include "C:\openCv\opencv\build\include\opencv2\nonfree\nonfree.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;





int main(){

cv::VideoCapture cap("video2.mp4");

if(!cap.isOpened()){  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;
}

Mat frame; // creates the object frame

FlannBasedMatcher matcher; //create object matcher


return 0;
}
```

it compiles but when i run i got an access violation. I tried to split the problem and i figured out that i have this error when i create the object FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

Any help is accepted, thank you very much.

I'm using visual studio express edition 2012 and opencv 242 under windows 7.

Now modifying slightly the code I get an interuption in free.c

```
/***
```

*free.c - free an entry in the heap
*
*       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
*
*Purpose:
*       Defines the following functions:
*           free()     - free a memory block in the heap
*
*******************************************************************************/

```
#include <cruntime.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <winheap.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <internal.h>
#include <mtdll.h>
#include <dbgint.h>
#include <rtcsup.h>

/***
*void free(pblock) - free a block in the heap
*
*Purpose:
*       Free a memory block in the heap.
*
*       Special ANSI Requirements:
*
*       (1) free(NULL) is benign.
*
*Entry:
*       void *pblock - pointer to a memory block in the heap
*
*Return:
*       <void>
*
*******************************************************************************/

void __cdecl _free_base (void * pBlock)
{

    int retval = 0;


    if (pBlock == NULL)
        return;

    RTCCALLBACK(_RTC_Free_hook, (pBlock, 0));

    retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);
    if (retval == 0)
    {
        errno = _get_errno_from_oserr(GetLastError());
    }
}
```

The interruption is in: if (retval == 0)

**SOLVED!**

I rebuilt openCv for VisualStudio 2012 using cMake and now works fine.

Comment: If the commented out code is not necessary please edit your question and remove it. If it's part of your program uncomment it and make sure it still compiles. You really should use a debugger to locate where it breaks and use the stack trace to locate the originating call site in your program.

Comment: thanks, i tried but i'm not so skilled in debugging. That's why i asked, the strange thing is that i followed the guide on opencv website and the syntax is the same.

Comment: code compiles fine here. please go and check the libs you linked, search for 32 / 64 bit mismatches, debug code linked against release libs or vice versa.

Comment: compiles fine also here, at execution it throws the access violation. I'm trying to build opencv for VS 2012 with cMake